# Deriving the Kalman filter using basic facts about normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability, kalman-filter

I'm attempting to derive the Kalman filter using basic facts about normally distributed random variables.  Can anyone complete this derivation?  Here's what I have so far (there could be some mistakes):

---

Let's assume that
\begin{align}
x_{k+1} &= \Phi_k x_k + w_k.
\end{align}
We don't know with certainty the value of $x_k$.  Rather, we view $x_k$ as a normally distributed random variable with a known mean $\mu_k$ and known variance $\Sigma_k$.
The noise vector $w_k$ is also not known with certainty -- rather, $w_k$ is a normally distributed random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\Omega_k$. The matrix $\Phi_k$ is assumed to be known.  We assume $w_k$ and $x_k$ are independent.

What do we know about the value of $x_{k+1}$?  From probability theory (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332441/affine-transformation-applied-to-a-multivariate-gaussian-random-variable-what)), we know that the random variable $x_{k+1}$ is normally distributed with mean $\Phi_k \mu_k$ and variance $\Phi_k \Sigma_k \Phi_k^T + \Omega_k$.  So far, this is the most we can say about $x_{k+1}$.

Next, what if we are given (as a measurement from a sensor) the value of the random variable
\begin{equation}
z_{k+1} = H_{k+1} x_{k+1} + v_{k+1},
\end{equation}
where the random variable $v_{k+1}$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\Gamma_{k+1}$ and is independent of $x_{k+1}$.  We assume the matrix $H_{k+1}$ is known.

First of all, note that $z_{k+1}$ is normally distributed with mean $H_{k+1} \Phi_k \mu_k$ and variance $H_{k+1}(\Phi_k \Sigma_k \Phi_k^T + \Omega_k) H_{k+1}^T + \Gamma_k$.  When we are given the value of $z_{k+1}$, we must update our beliefs about the value of $x_{k+1}$

**Question:** What are the (conditional) mean and variance of $x_{k+1}$ given the value of $z_{k+1}$?

Comment: It looks to me like your work so far is correct. In your first phase, you have found $p(x_{k+1} \mid z_{1:k})$, where $z_{1:k}$ refers to all past measurements. With the measurement likelihood $p(z_{k+1} \mid x_{k+1})$, we have a joint distribution $p(x_{k+1}, z_{k+1} \mid z_{1:k}) = p(z_{k+1} \mid x_{k+1}) p(x_{k+1} \mid z_{1:k})$, which will also be normal. Now you should be able to apply [standard techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) to this joint normal distribution to find $p(x_{k+1} \mid z_{1:k+1})$, which is your answer.