# What is the distribution of $B \cdot Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

I have a multivariate normal distribution $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$ and a non-singular matrix $B$.
I'd like to find the distribution of $X = B \cdot Y$.

So far I've written
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{P}(X \leq a) &=\mathbb{P}(B \cdot Y \leq a) =\mathbb{P}(Y \leq B^{-1} a) = f_Y(B^{-1}a) \\[0.2cm] &=
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2 \pi)^n \det(\Sigma)}} \cdot \exp \Big( -\frac{1}{2} (B^{-1}a - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (B^{-1}a - \mu) \Big).
\end{align*}

I think that $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu', \Sigma)$, for some $\mu'$, but I have no idea how to show this.

Comment: $$B\cdot Y \sim \mathcal{N}(B\cdot \mu,B\cdot \Sigma\cdot B^T)$$

Comment: To me the following expression seems to be wrong:$$\mathbb{P}(B \cdot Y \leq a) =
 \mathbb{P}(Y \leq B^{-1} a) =
 f_Y(B^{-1}a)$$

because  $$f_Y$$ looks like a pdf and $$\mathbb{P}(B \cdot Y \leq a) $$ looks like a cdf.

Comment: almost duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/332441).

Answer (score 1):

The wrong point in your reasoning is the equivalence:

$$\tag{1}BY \leq a \ \ \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ \ \ Y \leq B^{-1}a$$

Here is a simple counter example to (1) using $B=\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1}=B^{-1}$. More precisely, if  (1) were true, we would have the following equivalence:

$$\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1}\pmatrix{Y_x\\Y_y} \leq \pmatrix{a_x\\a_y} \ \ \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ \ \   \pmatrix{Y_x\\Y_y}\leq \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1}\pmatrix{a_x\\a_y}$$
Otherwise said:

$$\cases{\ \ Y_x \leq a_x\\-Y_y \leq a_y} \ \ \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ \ \ \cases{Y_x \leq \ \ a_x\\Y_y \leq -a_y}$$

The equivalence between the second lines is evidently false in general...