# Multiply normally distributed random vector by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem:

The random vector $X$ is normally distributed with $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Omega)$. $\mu $ is a column vector with $(\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3)$.

$\Omega$ is $3\times 3$ matrix. And $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Find the distribution of a random vector $Y$ where $Y = AX$.

How can I tackle this? Can I do the affine transformation here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Affine transformation applied to a multivariate Gaussian random variable - what is the mean vector and covariance matrix of the new variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332441/affine-transformation-applied-to-a-multivariate-gaussian-random-variable-what)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$X \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \mu_X, \Omega  \right) $.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Y] &= \mathbb{E}[AX]\\
&= A \mathbb{E}[X]\\
&= A \mu_X \\
\\
cov(Y) &= \mathbb{E} \left [ (Y - \mu_Y)(Y - \mu_Y)^T \right ]\\
&=   \mathbb{E} \left [ (AX- A\mu_X)(AX - A\mu_X)^T \right ]\\
&= A \mathbb{E} \left [ (X- \mu_X)(X - \mu_X)^T \right ]A^T\\
&= A \Omega A^T
\end{align*}

$Y \sim \mathcal{N} \left( A \mu_X, A \Omega A^T \right) $

Throughout, the assumption is that $A$ is a deterministic matrix and thus, can be pulled out of the expectation operator.

Comment: What an elegant and quick solution! Thank you!