# Distribution of a random vector nested by two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

The random vector $X$ is normally distributed with $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Omega)$. $\mu $ is a column vector with $(\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3)$.

$\Omega$ is $3\times 3$ matrix. $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix and $B$ is $2\times 3$ matrix.

Find the distribution of a random vector $W$ (2x1 ) where $W$ =

\begin{bmatrix}
    A\vec X \\
    B\vec X \\
    \end{bmatrix}

[Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632700/multiply-normally-distributed-random-vector-by-a-matrix)  to original (simpler) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write:$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\vec{X}\\
B\vec{X}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\\
B
\end{array}\right]\vec{X}$$ and characteristic for normal distribution is that this is enough to conclude that the vector again has normal distribution.

This with expectation: $$\mathbb{E}\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\\
B
\end{array}\right]\vec{X}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\\
B
\end{array}\right]\mathbb{E}\vec{X}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\\
B
\end{array}\right]\vec{\mu}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\vec{\mu}\\
B\vec{\mu}
\end{array}\right]$$

Its covariance matrix is:

$$\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\\
B
\end{array}\right]\Omega\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\\
B
\end{array}\right]^{T}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
A\\
B
\end{array}\right]\Omega\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A^{T} & B^{T}\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
A\Omega A^{T} & A\Omega B^{T}\\
B\Omega A^{T} & B\Omega B^{T}
\end{array}\right]$$

The normal distribution is completely determined by expectation and covariance.

Comment: Thank you! This is it!