# Distribution of Random Matrix by Vector

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, statistics, random-matrices, gaussian

The question is just a little variant of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332441/affine-transformation-applied-to-a-multivariate-gaussian-random-variable-what) but I thought to be careful based on the minor differences.

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ random matrix with *independent and identically distributed* entries sampled from $N(\mu,\sigma)$ and let $x$ be a (deterministic) vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$; here $\mu,\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\sigma>0$.  What is the distribution of the random vector
$$
Y= Ax.
$$
From the linked post, I know that it is Gaussian $N(\mu',\Sigma')$, since ultimately, $Y$ is an affine transformation of a normal random vector (when mapping $A$ into a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$).  However, what are the actual quantities $\mu'$ and $\Sigma'$?

I think it should be $Y\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\boldsymbol{0}_n , x^{\top}x\right)$ however, I'm not sure if I've made a mistake...

Comment: That is true only if the entries of $A$ are independent

Comment: @Exodd Am I correct that $Ax \sim N(0,x^{\top}x)$?

Comment: No, both mean and variance are incorrect

Comment: @Exodd oh, what would it be then?  I thought it was odd that it was centered at the origin and not at x...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition.

For any entry $Y_i$ of $Y$ we have
$$
Y_i = \sum_j A_{i,j} x_j
$$
and since the mean is linear,
$$
\mu'_i = \mathbb E[Y_i] = \sum_j \mathbb E[A_{i,j}] x_j = \mu\sum_j  x_j
$$

For the variance, notice that $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent whenever $i\ne j$, so the covariance matrix is diagonal. If you're not convinced, recall that the covariance is bilinear, so
$$
i\ne j\implies \Sigma_{i,j}' = Cov(Y_i,Y_j) = \sum_{s,k} Cov(A_{i,s},A_{j,k}) x_sx_k  = 0
$$
On the diagonal, we have (since the entries of $A$ are independent)
$$
\Sigma_{i,i}' = Cov(Y_i,Y_i) = Var(Y_i) = \sum_j Var(A_{i,j}) x_j^2 = \sigma^2\sum_j x_j^2
$$
so in the end you'd have
$$
Y\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu\sum_j  x_j \cdot \boldsymbol{1}_n ,  \sigma^2\sum_j x_j^2\cdot I_n\right)
$$

Comment: Ah this is very interesting.  So $Y$ can be sampled component-wise by drawing from $\mathcal{N}(\mu\sum_j x_j,\sigma^2\sum_j x_j^2)$...very interesting!  Thank you Exodd